# How to change frequency on ICL8038

Tags: frequency

I am making a frequencygenerator, that will have sine, triangular and square output (choosen with a rotary switch) but first, I'm having a problem with setting the right frequency with components. I've came to this schematics, where:

-SIN ADJ is from datasheets
-DC freq ADJ has connection, that will have a selection switch as duty cycle = 0.5 or adjustable with double switch

What I don't understand here is, what should I connect to Tcap or what capacitors should I select to cover the whole range (0.1 to 300 kHz) and how should be FM bias and SWEEP connected?

[The datasheet of ICL8038 is HERE](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/67443/INTERSIL/ICL8038.html)

[image]

Thanks for all the help in advance!

EDIT:

How to use the SWEEP and FM Bias pins? What exactly does these pins do?

Comment: All the info you need is in the data sheet as far as I can see. Read it.

Comment: https://www.intersil.com/content/dam/intersil/documents/an01/an013.pdf

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist: there isn't useful formula for his question.
He wants to know the equation on how to calculate the CAP : RES ratio for all the frequencies between 0.1 and 300k.

Comment: not true f=
0.33/
RC
-----------

Comment: Did you read the data sheet you linked to? How about page 5?

Comment: BTW this IC is obsolete

Comment: Sorry for late replay.
@TonyEErocketscientist: Is this formula used for all frequencies and/or duty cycles? If so, then the answer from "Jakey" is on spot. The values of 4.7uF to 470pf are quite okay. I will just add the 47uF capacitor to reach down to 0.1hz.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast:Yes, I've read the datasheet but those all equations were a bit confusing to me.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist: Yes, I know. And it's obsolete since 1996 (i think, haha). But it's the easiest way to do a frequency generator for home use with wide range of functions and adjustments.

Comment: @E.Wood  No , it's far easier to use Audacity and more powerful.  But yet any Logic Schmitt Inverter can easily do the same triangle, square wave variable f